# unable to resolve org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority even though it's downloaded/displayed under project libraries

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm busy with a spring boot course where I'm supposed to implement the Spring Security `GrantedAuthority` interface. But for some reason I'm unable to resolve the class, even though I can see that spring security has been downloaded.  I'm using spring security 4.2.3 and spring boot starter 1.5.8-release.

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> eclipse doesn't seem to be able to find `GrantedAuthority` in Spring Security and when I manually enter the import statement it's marked as an error. Any idea what else I can try/what might be the cause of this?

Comment: Are you using maven, gradle, ant, sbt, or any other build tools?  If so, does everything compile from the command line?  Sometimes IDES do wonky things.

Comment: @tfecw I use Maven.  I haven't tried compiling from the commandline.  what command can I use to compile from cmmandLine?  The project compiles without any errors however before I build eclipse warns me that there's errors in the workspace

Comment: On the command line try `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` then do a `mvn clean install` to package your application. This will force a redownload of all dependencies, could be that you have a borked jar. If that still doesn't work, force Eclipse to refresh the maven project.

Comment: @M. Deinum Thanks!!!  That did ti!!! i've tried deleting/recreating the same project a few times and seems like all that was needed was a purge/clean install... Please add that as the answer and please down vote the current answer as that doesn't help anyone...

Comment: Press [ctrl]+[shift]+[t] (open type) and type GrantedAuthority. If maven downloaded the class you should see it. Or try right click maven update project and check clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it happens that Maven, due to various reasons, downloads a broken jar. To fix this you can [purge the local maven repository](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html), this will remove all dependencies needed by your project from the local repository. The next build will download all dependencies from the remote repositories again.

To purge the local repository do a `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` afterwards do a `mvn clean install` to rebuild and redownload the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Intellij Idea ver 2020.2 and Gradle ver 6.6.1.
The answer was to choose from Idea's menu:
`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`

Of course it was necessary to add first to the `dependencies` section in the `build.gradle` file the line:
`compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")`